# XML how merge more element to one elements

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Thank you M. Kay. But I am tried your code and still not working. 
There is XSLT that does not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <Transakcie>
  <A1><xsl:apply-templates/></A1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Export/*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{substring-before(Export(), '_')}" select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</Transakcie>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And there is complete source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2014-04-12T13:31:13">
    <Export>
        <F_x003D_>140100378</F_x003D_>
        <Den_x003D_>29.01.2014</Den_x003D_>
        <Z_x003D_>26.25</Z_x003D_>
        <D_x003D_>5.25</D_x003D_>
        <S_x003D_>20</S_x003D_>
    </Export>
    <Export>
        <F_x003D_>140400002</F_x003D_>
        <Den_x003D_>07.01.2014</Den_x003D_>
        <Z_x003D_>-22.08</Z_x003D_>
        <D_x003D_>-4.42</D_x003D_>
        <S_x003D_>20</S_x003D_>
    </Export>
    <Export>
        <F_x003D_>140400008</F_x003D_>
        <Den_x003D_>20.01.2014</Den_x003D_>
        <Z_x003D_>-21.67</Z_x003D_>
        <D_x003D_>-4.33</D_x003D_>
        <S_x003D_>20</S_x003D_>
    </Export>
</dataroot>
```

And Output XML I need following:

```
<Transakcie>
    <A1 F="140100378" Den="2014-01-29" Z="26.25" D="5.25" S="20"/>
    <A1 F="140400002" Den="2014-01-07" Z="22.08" D="-4.42" S="20"/>
    <A1 F="140400008" Den="2014-01-20" Z="-21.67" D="-4.33" S="20"/>
</Transakcie>
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In this case providing more context for the example elements would be helpful, and knowing if they are part of a singular header for a file, or are repeated multiple times throughout the file would be good.

Comment: Your XSLT won't be processed because it is not *well-formed XML* (perhaps you could do some research about what makes a XML well-formed - you will understand the code better and might discover the errors easily). Take a look at your `</Transakcie>` tag. The opening tag is inside `<xsl:template match="/">...</xsl:template>`. So you have to close it there. Read your error messages. They might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The following would be a good start:

```
<xsl:template match="root"><!-- where 'root' is the containing element -->
  <A1><xsl:apply-templates/></A1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{substring-before(name(), '_')}" select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

I haven't tried to tackle the date reformatting, just add another template rule for this.